# Repackage EXE to MSI what software can I use?

Tags: windows-7

I need to create msi package for silent distribution across my network and I need to convert
the Google Chrome and other software to MSI package that is compatible with SSCM or any other
third party tools?

Anyone have experience or can recommend a good MSI packager?

Mike W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions:

- I would recommend AdminStudio from Flexera Software. I have used it
  in the past and it works fine.

  [AdminStudio](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/enterprise/products/application-packaging/adminstudio/)

  It compatible with SSCM and you can install all software MSI or not.
- Also there is EMCO Package Builder, easy to use and lot of features

  [EMCO Package Builder](http://emcosoftware.com/msi-package-builder)

*I'm not affiliated with those companies.*

Comment: I will try out all these programs thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome is [already available as an MSI](http://www.google.com/chrome/business/browser/admin/) so no repackaging is necessary.

Product recommendations are off-topic for this site, so you're not going to get any specific recommendations here.

Repackaging tools have generally not worked well for me. These tools seek to do something that, for very simple applications, is probably feasible but, for an application of any sufficient complexity, is likely not. Generally I find that packages created by these tools end up having "noise" in them that ends up needing to be cleaned out manually.

I try to avoid repackaging applications whenever possible. Unless you embark on a huge reverse-engineering effort you really can't be 100% sure that the package you create does exactly what the manufacturer's setup does. If the application's setup has unattended installation and removal options I prefer a script-based install using those options over a repackage.

Personally, when I need to package applications as MSIs I use the [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) to build a package from the ground up. You're guaranteed to get a package that does just what you want and has no unintended side effects. It's a lot of work, to be certain, but I think the results make it worth the work.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using EMCO MSI Package Builder with good success, and the price is also good!
but now I am trying out the ZOLA MSI Repackager from ZOLA Software and it works quite well
for me and has a good price!

Admin Studio works very well but I find the price to be too high for my usage at the moment.

EMCO Packager
http://www.emcosoftware.com

ZOLA MSI Tool
http://www.zolasoftware.com

Hope it helps.

Regards,
James Abram.